# Predict class and bounding rectangle

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I try to train a neural network image classifier for two classes (3 in fact -> the 2 classes and all the rest). After the network training, I would like to be able to add a bounding rectangle on the detected area if it is one of the two wanted classes.

My model is created like that:

```py
model = Sequential([
  data_augmentation,
  layers.Rescaling(1./255),
  layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Dropout(0.1),
  layers.Flatten(),
  layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(num_classes)
])
```

When I use the predict method, I just have a list of 1 input per class:

```py
predictions = model.predict(img_array, verbose=0)
# [[1.12, 4.10, 6.21]]
score = tf.nn.softmax(predictions[0])
prediction = class_names[np.argmax(score)]
```

So I can have the class name of the tested image but can't have the bounding rectangle of the ROI in the image that trigger the detection of the class in order to pixelate/blur this area. Did I miss something in the output of my model ?

Comment: You have trained a `classification` model. It would only give you the class labels as output. You **cannot** get the bounding box coordinates. You will have to train an `object detection` model to obtain those.

Answer (score 0):

**Sequential model** is for simple network design.

Suppose you have object coordinates information in your dataset.

For more complex network with multiple I/O, in your case (class probability with object coordinates), you should use [**Keras Functional API**](https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/) instead.